Observation: Python REPL is not a valid tool, try one of [python_repl_ast]. in Langchain
from langchain.agents import initialize_agent
from langchain.llms.fake import FakeListLLM
from langchain.agents import AgentType
from langchain_experimental.tools import PythonAstREPLTool
res = ["Action: Python REPL\nAction Input: print(2.2 + 2.22)", "Final Answer: 4.42"]
llm = FakeListLLM(responses=res)
agent = initialize_agent(tools=[PythonAstREPLTool()],
llm=llm, agent=AgentType.ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION, verbose=True
)
agent.run("what is 2.2 + 2.22?")

What's wrong in this code? I am getting the following error:

Can someone explain me the better way to implement a Fake LLM using Langchain?

and it is working when i used agent.run("what is ") only :(

The observation says it all. Use python_repl_ast instead of Python REPL. Following is the updated code:
from langchain.agents import initialize_agent
from langchain.llms.fake import FakeListLLM
from langchain.agents import AgentType
from langchain_experimental.tools import PythonAstREPLTool

res = ["Action: python_repl_ast\nAction Input: print(2.2 + 2.22)", "Final Answer: 4.42"]
llm = FakeListLLM(responses=res)
agent = initialize_agent(tools=[PythonAstREPLTool()], llm=llm, agent=AgentType.ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION, verbose=True)
agent.run("what is 2.2 + 2.22?")

Output:

